# Is it possible to edit stream network to correspond a new subwatersheds raster and then run r.stream.order?

Tags: grass-gis, stream-order

All rasters are created with `r.watershed`. So, I have:

- streams raster,
- accumulation and
- directions.

We know, that streams raster should correspond exactly to directions raster in order to use `r.stream.order`. But if I cleaned subwatersheds (removed too small) and added some new on desired points, I got a new subwatersheds raster, that doesn't correspond to streams.

Now, if I correct streams with `r.mapcalc`, it will not correspond to directions.

Is there a simple grass-gis way to correct streams by new subwatersheds and calculate orders with `r.stream.order`?

UPD: [image: subwatersheds]
UPD2: [image: transparent subs]
UPD3: [image: shaded]
UPD4: [image: short tributaries]

In UPD4 I add an image of too short streams, that are generated by r.watersheds and that are the cause of too small subwatersheds, whose area is much smaller that the threshold.

UPD5: I realized, why these small subs appear - the river on those sections is very wide, sometimes several km. r.watersheds does well the delineation job, but generates subs smaller than threshold because it doesn'tknow what to do with these sections within the wide river bed.
So, If I can't set up r.watershed, I have to eliminate these subwatersheds after creation. But then I loose streams-basins correspondance.
The soulution would be: to say to r.watershed that it shouldn't generate too short streams. But how?

I also created [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/465162/112339), because it seem to go off the initial question frame.

Comment: Not that I know. But the "correct" way to remove small subwatersheds is to use a larger threshold in the `r.watershed` command.

Comment: Sure, but I got much smaller subwatersheds along the main channel (don't know why). Also, I add some points after r.watershed is done to have some of subwatersheds exactly flowing to these points (that are for example gages or bridge-river crossings). This gives me some odd subwatersheds and in theory can result in some tiny ones.
I added the image to the main text.

Comment: For example, I would like to divide a big yellow subwatershed into 3 parts, and remove a great deal of these small along the channel. Could it be done only by variaating the threshold?

Comment: If you find the gage or bridge locations **exactly on the stream lines**, then you can use those X-Y coordinates as input to `r.water.outlet` to find the upstream drainage areas to those points. That should help with dividing a large area to smaller sub-watersheds.

Comment: I use snapping to locate all gages onto streams (thinned previously). And then I use r.stream.basins on gages points, then r.cross the result and basins (product of r.watershed). You propose to find each subwatershed with r.water.outlet and then make r.cross?

Comment: So you think it's better to first set up threshold to get rid of too small subwatersheds and then add subwatersheds in a cycle with t.water.outlet

Comment: All the same, I dont understand, why this yellow one is so big and those on the stream are so small. May be I should change divergence parameter?

Comment: The is an extra problem that I mentioned in the question: I would like to calculate orders, most important - I need for each subwatershed the underlying one (a receiving subwatershed), this is perfectly done with r.stream.order too. But I loss this possibility just after changing the basins map (because streams raster and subwatersheds raster are no more corresponding to each other)..

Comment: Once I finish the `r.watershed` module, I do not do any manipulation of the outputs. No thinning needed, the streams raster is always 1 pixel wide. Then, to get drainage area for a specific drain point, I zoom in very close to that drainage point, till I can see individual pixels on the stream network. I right-click on a pixel that is on the stream network to get the X-Y coords in the clipboard, then paste that into the `r.water.outlet` command.

Comment: Could the yellow drainage area be a valley bottom, with no basins larger than the threshold?

Comment: You mean an undrained area? Doesn't seem so, I added transparent subwatersheds to see the DEM through. The mentioned subwatershed is blue on the second image.

Comment: When I look at the first image, there are no tributaries to the stream line in the yellow basin. That suggests that there are no subwatersheds larger than the threshold. I'm not sure why those additional stream lines (what you refer to as subwatersheds) show up in the new blue basin. Perhaps create a shaded relief from the original DEM, and show that?

Comment: Here is the shaded DEM. These tributaries appear from DEM itself.

Comment: I added an image in UPD4, that shows small streams, that are guilty for these too small subs under threshold value. I don't know why r.watershed generates them. Tha image is a small part of basins raster, just after r.watershed procedure.

Comment: I know the cause, I wrote it in the quiestion body. But for now I don't know how to deal with without editing subwatersheds raster.