# How to set up r.watersheds if it generates too short streams on river valley sections that are too wide

Tags: grass-gis, flow-direction, r.watershed, pcraster

Related to [this question too](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/464571/112339)

I am delineating a very big watershed with very wide river valley.
When I tried to perform with PCRaster, the directions map wasn't generated properly, as sticks upon local DEM ridges and islands (that are situated within the river valley) and doesn't let river flow to the lower direction. So, PCRaster (in it's current state) is inapplicable to generate direction for very wide valleys.

The GRASS GIS r.watershed algorithm does the job well, but there are too short streams that are generated within wide sections of the river as can be seen on the image applied.
What is the state of the art of generating subwatersheds of defined threshold without getting these short streams and ergo too small, tiny subwatersheds?

I could of course correct the resulting raster of subwatersheds, but in that case I lose correspondence of subwatersheds and streams, and it it important for stream order calculations (I won't know which subwatersheds is corresponding to which stream after r.stream.order operation).
Of course I can use Python Pandas or any other approach to correct the table of raw streams and make it correspond to subwatersheds. But this way I can admit only if there is nothing in GRASS itself to set up r.watershed, or some other operation.

The illustration of too short streams:

[image: Here are too short streams generated]